# Manipulate/Change Keyboard Input in Jetpack Compose TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way in Jetpack Compose to manipulate each char that is entered in a `TextField` before it is actually displayed using a `mapper : (String) -> String` function that **might change over time.**

I tried implementing this with TextField

```
var value  by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(value = value, onValueChange = {
   //I could perform manipulation here
   value = it
})
```

But it doesn't work because it is manipulating the whole text instead of the most recent character. Also, it is causing predictable behavior when changing the cursor position or changing the mapper function during the process

*Note: `VisualTransformation` is also unsuitable. It is applied to the whole text*

I assume we have to approach this problem from another layer. Is there any way to achieve such behavior in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Have you tried the `visualTransformation` parameter to `TextField()`?

Comment: Here are a few [samples using `VisualTransformation`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/integration-tests/foundation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/demos/text/ComposeVariousInputField.kt).

Comment: @CommonsWare @adneal `visualTransformation` seems unsuitable since it's applied to the whole text

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar challenge that I had while implementing a text verification UI with compose. Since input focus is not in a ready state I ended up doing the following for input requiring numbers only.

```
onValueChange = {
        // only accept the first number value entered
        number = it.text.replace(Regex("\\D"), "").take(1)

        // move to the next field
        if (number.isNotEmpty()) {
            nextFocus?.requestFocus() ?: run {
                onVerifyPin?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }
```

Using regex and kotlin's last operator you could achieve the desired result.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html